# java regex replace special characters and spaces with dash

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string,

```
String model = "Town & Country";
```

I'd like to replace the special characters and the spaces with a dash as well as lower case it for a nice clean url.

Example

```
"town-country"
```

I've tried the following code.

```
"Town & Country".replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "-").toLowerCase();
```

but I ended up with the following output.

```
town---country
```

Could someone assist me with the regex so that this works properly? I if there is multiple spaces, I'd like to reduce it to a single space replaced by a dash. If there is a good java library out there designed to do this, I'd be interested in it, however I do not want to use pluses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close, you just need to add a quantifier to the expression to allow it to match more than one character.

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/
```

(Note the `+` at the end.)

So, your code should be this:

```
"Town & Country".replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "-").toLowerCase();
```

[**Live example on regexr**](http://regexr.com/3a9jh)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of the quantifier.