# Java Regular Expression not worked

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string source:

```
String source= "$This-is-(…-“demo”";
```

I need the result with separation of one desh (-) only with in between words like:

```
This-is-demo
```

I remove special characters and replace it with character "**-**"

```
String result = source.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]" + "\\s*", "-");
```

The results of running the program **result="-This-is-----demo-"**.

I use the following command with the expectation of removing the character "**-**" if it is greater than 2.

```
result.replaceAll("(--|---|----|-----|------|-------|--------|---------|----------)", "-")
```

my results: **-This-is---demo-** it incorrectly

FULL CODE

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "$This-is-(…-“demo”";
        String result= a.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]" + "\\s*", "-").trim().replaceAll("(--|---|----|-----|------|-------|--------|---------|----------)", "-");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: Please, show us what exactly doesn't work as needed. You might want to include expected output of this code to your question.

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope you continue to help me

Comment: You should explain why do you expect the dollar sign `$` to disapper. Also, check out this question, I think it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142947/java-regex-replace-special-characters-and-spaces-with-dash

Comment: That (horrible) second regex should probably be `-{2,}`. Or just do it all at once, e.g. `replaceAll("\\W+", "-")` (depending on the requirements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your problem and then resolved it. Use following in your code:
`source.replaceAll("[\\p{P}\\p{S}]", " ").trim().replaceAll("(     |    |   |  | )", "-");`
It gives the desired result string which you want.